# How to get the system library path on Unix (Linux, FreeBSD)

Tags: python, linux, unix, freebsd, library-path

I need a more-or-less portable programmatic way for querying the dynamic library path list. For Linux, I can concatenate the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf` (processing the `include` directives as needed and possibly filtering by architecture), but that doesn't work e.g. on FreeBSD.

Ultimately, I need a Python function for doing that. It can call gcc or other external commands if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For both Linux and FreeBSD you can try working through the output of `ldconfig(8)`. The options for listing the libraries are different though (`-p` on [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig), `-r` on [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ldconfig&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE&format=html).) Hope this helps.

#### Edit:

Solaris is different - see [`man crle`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/crle-1.html#scrolltoc).
Mac OSX is different yet again - see [`man dyld`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html).

Comment: Do you have anything for other Unix systems, like the Mac OS X or Solaris?

Comment: I believe OSX should be pretty close to FreeBSD, while Solaris should be similar to Linux. Hmmm ... not exactly - updating the post.